# Can we execute a python script within SPFX webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, python

I have a python script which uses some python libraries to do decrypting and encryption . Is there a way where I can invoke this script inside the webpart code.

Answer (score 1):

No, SPFx web parts are entirely client side. You could however create an Azure function using Python and then expose an API that your SPFx web part could call:

[Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators)